# VBA Issue with GoTo in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro, which I would like after the last msgbox and after clicking "YES" to go next part of macro (open file), but when i clicked YES Macro stops working without error, as if I didn't know what to do next.

```
Dim data_wb2 As Workbook
Beep
CarryOn = MsgBox("Czy Chcesz uzupełnić plik CMR - LRJ_MINIMAL?", vbYesNo, "Czy kontynuować?")
If CarryOn = vbYes Then
Else 
GoTo Jump
MyFolder = "xxxxx"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\CMR - LRJ_MINIMAL_*.xlsx")
If MyFile <> "" Then
Set data_wb2 = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
Dim PvtKraje As PivotTable
Dim data_wb As Workbook
Jump:
Beep
CarryOn = MsgBox("Czy Chcesz uzupełnić plik xxxx_po krajach?", vbYesNo, "Czy kontynuować?")
If CarryOn = vbYes Then
Else
GoTo Jump_Sheet

MyFolderKRAJ = "xxxx"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\xxx_mm_yyyy_podział po krajach*.xlsx")
If MyFile <> "" Then
Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make much sense, but if you're using `Goto` like that you really need to restructure your code instead.

Comment: @Rory hi its cut my code, i put rest part of my code with edited post.

Comment: Almost all of the code you have posted is in the `Else` part of an `If` block, so if  you answer  Yes to the first message, none of that will run.

Comment: so Else should be on end of my part code :`If MyFile <> "" Then
Set data_wb2 = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
Dim PvtKraje As PivotTable
Dim data_wb As Workbook Else 
GoTo Jump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not 100% clear for me but if you want to open the file after clicking 'yes' on the msgBox you do not need to work with jump functions.
I would avoid jump functions in general because it leads to confusing code.
You also need to end the `If` statement using `End If`.
Please also avoid using the same bool name `CarryOn` two times in one `If` statement

Pls try the following code:

```
CarryOn1 = MsgBox("Czy Chcesz uzupełnić plik CMR - LRJ_MINIMAL?", vbYesNo, "Czy kontynuować?")
If CarryOn1 = vbYes Then
   Beep
   CarryOn2 = MsgBox("Czy Chcesz uzupełnić plik xxxx_po krajach?", vbYesNo, "Czy kontynuować?")
   If CarryOn2 = vbYes Then
      MyFolder = "xxxxx"
      MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\CMR - LRJ_MINIMAL_*.xlsx")
      If MyFile <> "" Then
         Set data_wb2 = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
      End If
   Else
      GoTo Jump_Sheet
   End If
Else
   GoTo Jump_Sheet
End If
```

Comment: I use the jump function due to the fact that after completing this file, another message will appear about the possibility of filling another document, if in the previous window you click No, it should go to the next document, if Yes should open the file

Comment: So first MsgBox: 1.Yes (ask for filling it with second MsgBox) 2. No (next document)
Second MsgBox: 1.Yes(open the file) 2. (next document)

right?

Comment: exactly are you saying

Comment: Okay then try the code above now